# React-Router Parsing error: Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use react-redux with an navbar to switch components with react-router but i get this error i have tried to search for the problem but i can't find any answer?
When click for example on Update Robot button i want to switch to that component for example and i have 5 components i want to switch between?

Line 75:150:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

```
 73 | </header>
  74 |       <Switch>                                               
> 75 |        <Route exact path='/addRobo' component={<AddRobot  get_name={get_name} get_username={get_username} get_email={get_email} add_robot={add_robot}}/>

I don't get it?
And below is my code?

import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import {
    Router,
    Route,
    Link
} from 'react-router';
import {
    connect
} from 'react-redux';
import {
    setSearchField,
    requestRobots,
    setName,
    setUserName,
    setEmail,
    addRobot,
    updateRobot,
    deleteRobot
} from '../actions';
import CardList from '../components/CardList';
import SearchBox from '../components/SearchBox';
import Scroll from '../components/Scroll';
import ErrorBoundry from '../components/ErrorBoundry';
import AddRobot from '../components/AddRobot';
import UppdateRobot from '../components/UpdateRobot';
import DeleteRobot from '../components/DeleteRobot';
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar.js';


import './App.css';

// parameter state comes from index.js provider store state(rootReducers)
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        searchField: state.searchRobots.searchField,
        robots: state.manage_data.robots,
        isPending: state.manage_data.isPending,
        name: state.manage_data.name,
        username: state.manage_data.username,
        email: state.manage_data.email,
    }
}

// dispatch the DOM changes to call an action. note mapStateToProps returns object, mapDispatchToProps returns function
// the function returns an object then uses connect to change the data from redecers.
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onSearchChange: (event) => dispatch(setSearchField(event.target.value)),
        onRequestRobots: () => dispatch(requestRobots()),
        get_name: (event) => dispatch(setName(event.target.value)),
        get_username: (event) => dispatch(setUserName(event.target.value)),
        get_email: (event) => dispatch(setEmail(event.target.value)),
        add_robot: () => dispatch(addRobot()),
        uppdate_robot: () => dispatch(updateRobot())
    }
}

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.userinfo);
        this.props.onRequestRobots();
    }

    render() {
        const {
            robots,
            searchField,
            onSearchChange,
            isPending,
            get_name,
            name,
            get_username,
            username,
            get_email,
            email,
            add_robot,
            uppdate_robot
        } = this.props;
        const stylecur = {
            fill: 'currentcolor'
        };
        const filteredRobots = robots.filter(robot => {
            return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase());
        })
        return ( <
            Router >
            <
            div className = 'tc' >

            <
            header className = "bg-white black-80 tc pv4 avenir" >
            <
            a href = ""
            className = "bg-black-80 ba b--black dib pa3 w2 h2 br-100" >
            <
            svg className = "white"
            data - icon = "skull"
            viewBox = "0 0 32 32"
            style = {
                stylecur
            } >
            <
            title > skull icon < /title><path d="M16 0 C6 0 2 4 2 14 L2 22 L6 24 L6 30 L26 30 L26 24 L30 22 L30 14 C30 4 26 0 16 0 M9 12 A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 9 21 A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 9 12 M23 12 A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 23 21 A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 23 12"></path > < /svg> <
            /a> <
            h1 className = "mt2 mb0 baskerville i fw1 f1" > RoboFriends < /h1> <
            h2 className = "mt2 mb0 f6 fw4 ttu tracked" > Create an ensembe of Robot with your friends! < /h2> <
            nav className = "bt bb tc mw7 center mt4" >
            <
            a className = "f6 f5-l link bg-animate black-80 hover-bg-lightest-blue dib pa3 ph4-l"
            href = "/" > Home < /a> <
            a className = "f6 f5-l link bg-animate black-80 hover-bg-light-green dib pa3 ph4-l"
            href = "/portfolio" > < Link to = {
                '/addRobo'
            }
            className = "nav-link" > Add Robot < /Link></a >
            <
            a className = "f6 f5-l link bg-animate black-80 hover-bg-light-blue dib pa3 ph4-l"
            href = "/shop" > < Link to = {
                '/updateRobo'
            }
            className = "nav-link" > Update Robot < /Link></a >
            <
            a className = "f6 f5-l link bg-animate black-80 hover-bg-light-pink dib pa3 ph4-l"
            href = "/about" > < Link to = {
                '/searchRobo'
            }
            className = "nav-link" > Search Robot < /Link></a >
            <
            a className = "f6 f5-l link bg-animate black-80 hover-bg-light-yellow dib pa3 ph4-l"
            href = "/contact" > < Link to = {
                '/delRobo'
            }
            className = "nav-link" > Delete Robot < /Link></a >
            <
            /nav> <
            /header> <
            Switch >
            <
            Route exact path = '/addRobo'
            component = {
                < AddRobot get_name = {
                    get_name
                }
                get_username = {
                    get_username
                }
                get_email = {
                    get_email
                }
                add_robot = {
                    add_robot
                }
            }
            /> <
            Route exact path = '/updateRobo'
            component = {
                < UppdateRobot get_name = {
                    get_name
                }
                get_username = {
                    get_username
                }
                get_email = {
                    get_email
                }
                uppdate_robot = {
                    uppdate_robot
                }
            }
            /> <
            Route exact path = '/searchRobo'
            component = {
                < SearchBox searchChange = {
                    onSearchChange
                }
            }
            /> <
            Route exact path = '/delRobo'
            component = {
                < DeleteRobot / >
            }
            /> <
            /Switch>   <
            Scroll > {
                isPending ? < h1 > Loading < /h1> : <
                ErrorBoundry >
                <
                CardList robots = {
                    filteredRobots
                }
                /> <
                /ErrorBoundry>
            } <
            /Scroll> <
            /div> <
            /Router>
        );
    }
}

// action done from mapDispatchToProps will channge state from mapStateToProps
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't close `<AddRobot` tag.

```
component = {
                < AddRobot get_name = {
                    get_name
                }
                get_username = {
                    get_username
                }
                get_email = {
                    get_email
                }
                add_robot = {
                    add_robot
                }
                /> // Add this
            }
```

Comment: Thanks your an angel now i got another error but i am gonna accept this answer:)